# C - mkfifo , ls - don't stop

Tags: c, bash, ls, tr

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(void) {


    if(mkfifo("fifo", S_IRWXU) < 0 && errno != EEXIST) {
        perror("Fifo error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0) /*dziecko*/
    {
        int fifo_write_end = open("fifo", O_WRONLY);

        if(fifo_write_end < 0)
        {
            perror("fifo_write_end error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(dup2(fifo_write_end, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
        {
            perror("dup2 fifo_write_end error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", "-al", NULL) < 0)
        {
            perror("execlp error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }


    if(pid > 0) /*rodzic*/
    {
        int fifo_read_end = open("fifo", O_RDONLY);

        if(fifo_read_end < 0)
        {
            perror("fifo_read_end error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(dup2(fifo_read_end, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
        {
            perror("dup2 fifo_read_end error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        int atxt = open("a.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRWXU);

        if(atxt < 0)
        {
            perror("a.txt open error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(dup2(atxt,STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
        {
            perror("dup2 atxt error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(execlp("/usr/bin/tr", "tr", "a-z", "A-Z", NULL) < 0)
        {
            perror("tr exec error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }

    if(pid < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Program doesn't stop . I have no idea why . It should execute ls -al | tr a-z A-Z and write it in file a.txt.

And if someone can , please explain me how to do  ls-al | tr a-z A-Z | tr A-Z a-z > a.txt . For another tr I need second mkfifo right ? I'm not sure how it's working and if should i close write or read descriptor here . With "pipe" it was nesesery.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

The read end of the pipe won't report EOF until the pipe is closed. And a pipe isn't closed until **all** the descriptors that refer to it are closed. After you call `dup2`, the pipe is referenced by both the original FD and the descriptor that you duped it to. You need to close the original FD.

```
    if(dup2(fifo_write_end, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
    {
        perror("dup2 fifo_write_end error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(fifo_write_end);
    if(execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", "-al", NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror("execlp error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Another problem is that the process running `tr` needs to dup the FIFO to `stdin`, not `stdout`. So

```
    if(dup2(fifo_read_end, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
    {
        perror("dup2 fifo_read_end error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

should be

```
    if(dup2(fifo_read_end, STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
    {
        perror("dup2 fifo_read_end error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , it works after close read , but what with second TR . I need second  mkfifo?

Comment: Yes, you need a FIFO for each pipe. BTW, why are you using FIFOs instead of calling `pipe()`?

Comment: It's a task in my studies. To be clear , where should be second fifo ? There will be 2 forks , first like up  and second in child to make "grandchild " right ?

Comment: So there sould be ,  ls  in grandchild , first tr  in child ,  and second tr  in parent , but should I make secound mkfifo after child but before parent ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you create the second FIFO.

Comment: Damn , it checked wrong code , you tip's don't work :/ http://wklej.org/id/2270276/  it's still doesn't work

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can you help me with second tr ? Closing it doesn't mater here , there was stupid mistike , OUT instead of IN like You said.